# Basics on Empty List in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie in Python, and I only have been programming in the language for the third day. I convert from Matlab because I am graduating from university and I just cannot afford the heavy cost of the software.

I am trying to add several filenames to a list, which fails. The following is my code:

```
    import os
    dirname = r"D:\MyFiles"
    temp = os.listdir(dirname)
    fl = []
    for fn in temp:
        if fn.startswith('L0116'):
            fl = fl.append(fn)
```

What I don't understand is, the variable fl when initiated with [] returns as the list type, but then I fail to append the list with the above loop. I recheck my code using interactive prompt and I found out that the type changes to str and fails to append more.

I am stuck at this and I tried to google for about an hour without any clear clue to how I should do this.

Is there a better way? Or which part did I do it wrong?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `append()` method mutates the list in place. You should just append `fn` like this:

```
fl.append(fn)
```

don't try to assign the result of `fl.append(fn)` (which is `None`, by the way)

Also, don't use `r"foo"` strings for filenames. They are designed for use with regular expressions and using them for filenames or other kinds of strings will bite you. For example, you cannot end such a string with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks! Concept-problem after all.

Comment: However, if I do not add the r in front, the listdir function will read the the character after '\' and render errors. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Use `"D:\\MyFiles"`. Yes, it's ugly to have to double every pathname separator. Considering the backslash has been used as a string escape character for many decades, it was a very poor choice to use it also as a pathname separator. But that's what you're stuck with now if you're stuck with MS Windows.

Comment: Thank you again!
And yes!! ARGH. The more I code the more I hate MS Windows, though I admit that Win7 looks good.

Comment: @Celada: r'' is perfectly acceptable for filenames. It is not "designed for regexps". It is designed as a string that doesn't have escapes.

Comment: @LennartRegebro [This source](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash) is pretty official ans says r'' is designed "chiefly" for regexp. See also this [this semi-humourous story](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash) that tells the tale of how using r'' strings for filenames will bite you.

Comment: That doesn't "bite" you. You get a syntax error. Perfectly trivial. But yes, if you need to end with a backslash, it gets ugly.

Comment: in fact I got bitten by the folder name ending with backslash when I was experimenting with my script.

Answer (score 2):

`append` works inplace, so no need to assign it to the list itself (`fl = fl.append(fn)`) just do `fl.append(fn)`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension:

```
import os
dirname = r"D:\MyFiles"
fl = [fn for fn in os.listdir(dirname) if fn.startswith('L0116')]
```

Answer (score 0):

List append in python does not return a type, instead, you simply call the method like so:

```
import os
dirname = r"D:\MyFiles"
temp = os.listdir(dirname)
fl = []
for fn in temp:
    if fn.startswith('L0116'):
        fl.append(fn)
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work. Your logic was resetting the list every time.